Password entropy, or at least establishing reasonable upper and lower bounds on it
I use, and have always used, cryptographically secure randomness as a source for my passwords. However, the final coding of that random stream into something a website will accept as a password has varied over the years. I have to provide passwords for several people, and they often have to be written down, or communicated by voice.
My previous scheme selected from a short dictionary of short capitalised words, in a fixed pattern with some digits. It resulted in a low actual entropy of between 2 and 3 bits per character.
The highest practical encoding entropy with ASCII is essentially MIME, giving 6 bits per character. It is still over 5.8 when I demand no 'Ol10I' characters, and if you have difficulty telling which of those characters is which, well, that's why!
Unfortunately, the completely random mix of upper, lower and digits makes transferring by voice, or entering it from a piece of paper, difficult and error-prone.
A pass phrase, something like 'horse battery staple correct' is, notwithstanding its length, easier to communicate and enter than a random string of characters half its length. However, very few websites accept a string like that as a password as they 1) tend to demand a mix of upper, lower and digits 2) don't like the dictionary words included and 3) object to the length. Not current NIST/GCHQ guidance, but still widely met in practice.
I have therefore started using a coding scheme that applies enough of a pattern to the choices to ease transcription, while trying not to sacrifice too much entropy in the process.
I am having difficulty computing what the entropy actually is, though I have some estimates and bounds on it. It is certainly much better than 3 bits, probably somewhat better than 4, and probably less than 5 bits per character. Are any of you able to give me tighter bounds for the entropy?
The idea is pick a few successive characters from one alphabet, and to change alphabets often, so they 'chunk' nicely for transcription. The groups are randomly 2 or 3 characters long, which feature is perhaps my biggest obstacle to an entropy computation that I can get my head around. An example, generated just now, would be '575MYFdjcSC44TC'.
The algorithm for encoding is as follows. The three alphabets are the 8 digits 2 to 9, and the 23 lower case and upper case characters, each without the letters 'OoIiLl'.
I use random bytes from my cryptographic source very wastefully for convenience, but with effectively infinite length, who cares? Each byte is taken modulo the length of the choices at any stage. Obviously when this is not 2^n, this will introduce a slight bias, which is the least of my worries, and easily corrected for.
The first three groups are constrained to use all three alphabets. This is so that even the shortest password will contain upper, lower and digits.
For the first group, I take the first byte modulo 6, which chooses one of the three alphabets, and a group length of 2 or 3 characters. I then take the next 2 or 3 bytes, each modulo 8 or 23, to select the actual characters.
The second group takes the next byte modulo 4, to choose a length of 2 or 3 from one of the remaining alphabets, the characters selected as before.
The third group takes characters from the remaining alphabet, length chosen by the next byte modulo 2.
All subsequent groups take the next byte modulo 4, to choose the length, and which of the other two alphabets to change to, there is always a change of alphabet from group to group.
As a very loose and trivial lower bound, there are obviously at least 3 bits per character.
There is an apparent 5.75 bits (log2(23+23+8)) per character, if the encoding algorithm is not known.
The lowest actual entropy I would have for the first 8 characters is 4 digits (4x3 bits) plus 4 alpha characters (4x4.5 bits) plus 2.5 bits for the ordering of the three alphabets plus 3 for the group lengths, giving about 35 bits, or nearly 4.5 per character. Which is all quite consistent with my bound estimates at the start of the question.
Is there a systematic way to treat the variable length groups, especially for longer passwords? I don't want to generate enough examples to count the probabilities by brute force.

If verbal password transmission is the problem, that was solved hundreds of years ago. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NATO_phonetic_alphabet.

Both NIST and our GCHQ/NCSC now recommend pass phrases that are easy to remember but difficult to guess.  Password complexity is so passé.

I can't recommend enough that simple nudge: ask users to choose a passphrase, rather than a password.

@PaulUszak of course ICAO for each individual letter, however the grouping makes it faster and more robust, to say 'upper' and then rattle off several letters. BTW, have you come across the Irish/Belgian (or whatever is your national butt of jokes) ICAO alphabet? Able, babble, cable, dabble, enable, fable, gable ....

A passphrase doesn't need to be remembered. They also have the benefit of being easier to spell than random strings (especially if the phrase is in a language you know well). That's probably why they've started to be used in places where random strings would also have been an option. They are generally also easier to communicate by voice, since that was one of your use cases. So instead of your string converter idea, maybe use the hash value as seed for a random word generator instead?

@n-l-i maybe I'm missing something, why doesn't a passphrase need to be remebered? Perhaps you write it down, or record it in a passphrase file?

@Neil_UK Yes that's what I meant. It seemed like your solution was meant to make it easier to write down, read, and pronounce a password key. Therefore I assumed that it was either going to be written down or used as a one time key, and thought you might as well try to generate a few random words than generate a random string.

@n-l-i - True, I suppose 'battery correct horse staple' is easier to transcribe, and remember for 30 seconds, and easier to type, notwithstanding it's twice as long as '575MYFdjcSC44TC'. It however fails the (now discredited but still widely used) password strength test of many websites of needing upper and digits as well as lower case, may fail 'dictionary words' tests, and will be too long for some of them. But, I will think on your suggestion.

@n-l-i following this discussion, I think I will edit my question substantially to provide better context, while being exactly the same query.

Yes, keep editing.

@PaulUszak apart from possibly reducing excessive length, what else is needed from more editing?

By focusing on what the real question is.  Observe the voting.

Focusing on just the ordering of the groups we see that the first three have less combinations than the rest since they have to contain all three group types. The first group has 3 possibilities, the second has 2, and the third has only one. The remaining groups all have three possibilities, so we get $3!*3^{(n-3)}$ possibilities for $n$ groups.
The group lengths can be either 2 or 3 characters, meaning there's 2 possibilities per group, except potentially the last one depending on where the cutoff happens in regards to password length. We get $2^n$ possibilities for $n$ groups.
In total, that's $3!*3^{(n-3)}*2^n$ possible group combinations for $n$ groups with 3 distinct alphabets. Add to that the 8 or 23 characters in each alphabet and you have the basis for the entropy calculation.
